# trigger azure pipeline from another repo, on tag

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to trigger a pipeline when another repo is tagged.

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: myrepo
      name: myproject/my-repo
      ref: main
      type: git
      trigger:
        tags:
          include:
            - "*"
```

I can run the pipeline manually, but it's not triggered via tag in the referenced repo.

I have also tried to provide a specific tag for test purposes. Which also didn't work when creating a tag from main branch via the UI.

```yaml
tags:
  include:
    - "*"
```

Another thing I have tried is using the branch trick, which has helped me in the past for pipeline resources.

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/tags/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't work for some reasons or I didn't find the way to make it work.
A possible workaround solution would be, if you create a simple pipeline in your source repo, which is triggered on new tag and just runs through or maybe does some validation work if needed. In your target pipeline you create a trigger for it like that:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: myrepo-pipeline
    source: myrepo-pipeline-build
    trigger: true
```

If the first pipeline successfully runs, it triggers the actual pipeline.